# Intercept Vive controller input?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, htc-vive, openvr, steamvr

I'm building an openvr app for steamvr to assist with seated play (my room is small so my tracking area isn't ideal). My app pretty much just adjusts the play-area height when I hold the grip button and "scroll" on the touchpad so that I can reach objects that are too low/high at variable heights. (I tried "OpenVR Advanced Settings" but the options for keybinding with it is limited to simple button presses so I decided to make my own version).

I'd like to prevent touchpad input from being sent to the game while the grip button is being held, so that the moving on the touchpad doesn't cause movement in game, is this possible at all?

I'm assuming it's not possible, but wondering whether anyone has had any experience with this.

Comment: The movement on the touchpad causes movements in the game only if you implemented this somewhere, right? So you should be able to do this only if grip button is not pressed

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I'm developing the overlay app to be used in games, I do not have access to game code of course. I'm using SteamVR.instance.hmd.GetControllerState to check the state of the buttons/touchpad on controllers, my app does not send those inputs, it's listening for them. I'm wondering whether steamvr has any function to eat an input instead of sending it to the game, I think I recall seeing an example of it somewhere but I don't remember.

Comment: oh ok now I see

Answer (score 0):

After your clarification in the comments the answer is no, you can not "eat up" device inputs in an application, I usually work on OpenVR drivers and there after you submit a device input and/or any other event its available to anything that expects pose update events, and event subscribers can not stop others from receiving the said events

However there might be a work around (if its still an issue) I know of at least 1 application that can do what you want and that application is OVR Toolkit (when the overlay is active and you try to click something in the overlay, the game running in parallel will not receive the input, however that will only happen if OVR Toolkit overlay surface receives input, it may be a built in OpenVR overlay feature and you don't have to do anything or it can be defined by the developer, I don't really have a want to test this right now)

Sadly though OVR Toolkit is not open source, but there is an open source toolkit for unity for making overlays, which is open source and might be the solution you're looking for, it can be found [here](https://github.com/benotter/OVRLay)